Bootstrap overriding table styling in custom style sheet
I currently went from bootstrap v4 to v5 and and am trying to go through and fix any changes that might have been broken. I'm coming across this one that I cant figure out.
Table is not displaying the <th> tag correctly. my table thead th tags in my custome css sheet are getting overridden by table > :not(caption) > * > * in the tables.scss sheet in bootstrap.


/* Bootstrap */
.table> :not(caption)>*>* {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  color: var(--bs-table-color-state, var(--bs-table-color-type, var(--bs-table-color)));
  background-color: var(--bs-table-bg);
  border-bottom-width: var(--bs-border-width);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px var(--bs-table-bg-state, var(--bs-table-bg-type, var(--bs-table-accent-bg)));
}


/* custom css sheet */
table thead th {
  border-right: 1px solid #939393;
  background: #666;
  background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  background-position-x: 0%;
  background-position-y: 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 33px 12px 12px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<table id="table-id" class="table table-striped table-hover" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr class="row">
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table-app-config-list" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 150px;" aria-label="label here">TITLE HERE</th>




.table > :not(caption) > * > * has a specificity of 0, 1, 1, while table thead th has the lower specificity of 0, 0, 3. Using :is(table, .table) thead th instead will be sufficient.

how would this look? just replace table thead th with :is(table, .table) thead th {} or is there something in front of the :is(table, .table) thead th?

Just replace it.
